# How to convert ResultSet object to one specific POJO class object?

Tags: java, resultset

1. For example i have a Resultset which contain Details about Employee details and I have a table For Employee in database and i am selecting all details from that
2. I have java POJO class which resembles Employee Table what is the best method to implement convert result set into Employee class object
3. what is the best way to implement if i have multiple classes Like Employee and multiple tables too how to write a reusable code.

I am Using following notation now.

```
public Employee{

    private int empId;

    public setEmpId(int empId){
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public int getEmpId(){
        return this.empId;
    }
}

public class SetResultSetToEmployee{

    public Employee getEmployee(){
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setEmpId(resultSet.getInt("EmpId"));
        return e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Mybatis, or ORM like Hibernate may be your best solution.
But, if you really need to use jdbc's ResultSet, and want to convert ResultSet into java Beans, you can check:

1. ResultSetDynaClass of [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/ResultSetDynaClass.html) from apache.
2. or, write a bit code yourself like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372152/Mapping-JDBC-ResultSet-to-Object-using-Annotations).

Comment: Thnaks for sharing your thoughts its looking nice for my development but i have one Ques:if there may be more complex join in database and if database column name changes from one resultset to another how can i manage (can i able to give more alias-names for annotations in POJO)

Comment: try add alias name when `select` like this: `select orig_name as alias_name from XXXtable`

Comment: will you please tell me how to create our own annotations thanks in advance

Comment: @Prakash you doesn't need create your own annotaions, you just need use the annotation in package javax.persistence. In simplest words, this `@Target({METHOD}) public @interface YourAnnotation { }` create a custom annotation `YourAnnotation`, which can annotate method.

Answer (score 1):

> I have java POJO class which resembles Employee Table what is the best
>   method to implement convert result set into Employee class object

- If you are aware of `JPA`, then that will be best bet.. You won't
  have to do a typecast to get your POJO object.. JPA works on ORM
  (Object Relational Mapping). It directly Maps your `POJO` object to
  Database table.. And when you can directly fetch your object from
  database..
- And if you have no other choice than using `JDBC`, then you have no
  other choice than `TypeCasting`.

> what is the best way to implement if i have multiple classes Like
>   Employee and multiple tables too how to write a reusable code.

- In case of JDBC, I don't know what kind of Re-usability you are
  looking for, but you can implement a `DB` class, and have all your
  `Query Templates` there.. For any query you want to execute, you can
  use that class.. That be comparatively better to go with rather than
  have discrete queries, scattered all over your application..
- Again if you can use JPA, there is a concept of `Entities`.. If you
  want to work with multiple fetch, update or insert with database, it will be easier for
  you.. You can just get appropriate object and dump it in a instance
  of your `Entity`, or dump your object into your database without worrying about any kind of `Queries`.

**For a start of JPA, you can start with any of these links: -**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html
- [JPA-101-Java-Persistence-Explained](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363883/JPA-101-Java-Persistence-Explained)
- [Defining-Your-Object-Model-with-JPA](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363863/Defining-Your-Object-Model-with-JPA)

Comment: Thank you but i am using JDBC now. what is ment by Query Templates that you have mentioned will you please explain me with one example

Comment: @Prakash.. You can have all the `queries` in a single class.. All queries just need `Query String`.. So, you can call appropriate query and pass the query string.. That query string will be replaced executed upon to give you desired result..

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to write reusable codes use ORM tools like http://www.hibernate.org/.