# convert json string to POJO JAKSON

Tags: android, jackson

I am using JAKSON in my Android Project. Now i have a JSON Object in String format. How can i convert this String into a JAVA POJO class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12812692/646806

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to archive this:

1) Use [org.json.JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), mannually parse data and put it in POJO.

2) Use third party library like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and decode your JSON string directly to Object. GSON for example, use annotations to define serrialization/deserrialization rules for Objects/JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

With Jackson:

```
MyThing thing = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, MyThing.class);
```

For an introduction to using Jackson, I recommend taking a look at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
PojoClassName Obj = mapper.readValue(JsonString, PojoClassName.class);
```

P.S JsonString is the String which contains Json and is to be converted to POJO